# Undefined variable: hit

Tags: php, yii2

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку, сделал магазин на yii2, перенес на хостинг и переходы по категориям и карточке товара перестали работать. Как я понял это надо передать в контроллерах переменную $hit, но а как это сделать я без понятия, только начал изучать yii2

Сайт http://asvpage.ru

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нету переменной этой в контроллере) 
Составь запрос на его получение, если он не нужен - просто удали)

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста как составить этот запрос, или какой-то пример или объяснение как это делается))

Comment: $hit = Product::find()->where(твои условия)->one();

Comment: это в actionView надо сделать запрос ?

Comment: Именно там, да, потом передать в представление в функции render()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере нужно составить запрос на получения хита:

```
$hit = Product::find()->where([условия])->one();
```

Затем передать его в функцию **render();**